# SQL query to return top line manager by area

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

We are trying to populate our User table with the top manager of the Site (consider its like a department or cost centre) to help define an Owner of the Site.

EG:

[image]

in the example above, we would want to return employee "1002" to update "Owner" within all records where site = '123'

the difficulty we have is there are 90,000 employee records with a giant number of management structures within the Site.  It could be 1 level of management, it could be 5...

I am a novice when it comes to SQL, and I am baffled.  I'm not even sure it is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From your dataset example, is it safe to say that the highest number `EmployeeID`, within the `Site`, will have the `LineManager` as the `Owner` for the `Site`?

Comment: Based on your example, would 1103 be returned as the owner of site 567? Or would there need to be an employee record for 1103 that has a different site than 567? Your selection criteria isn't really clear, and has a big impact on how to design the query to return the results you want.

Comment: Sorry, 1234 & 2345 & 3456 & 5678 would return the 1002 at the Owner

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the definition of a Site owner would be someone who:

a) Is a line manager within the site, and 
b) Doesn't have a different site manager within the same site

Translating this to SQL:

```
update employee a set Owner = (
    select EmployeeId from employee b where b.Site = a.Site 
        and exists (select 1 from employee c where c.Site = b.Site and c.LineManager = b.EmployeeId)
        and not exists (select 1 from employee d where d.Site = b.Site and d.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId and d.LineManager <> b.EmployeeId)
)
```

Please see if this definition makes sense and run it by the business. I'm assuming there are no dupes by EmployeeID.

Comment: The easiest way I could define is the 1st line manager to exist where the line manager does not share the same site number.

Comment: That doesn't rely on the org. chart and thus may be a precarious assumption if things change. Besides, your sample doesn't have time stamp, how are you gonna determine "the 1st"? By min. ID? What if they are let go and a new one has a higher ID than subordinates?

Comment: The idea would be to use a tool we have to query the data and write over every night once our extract from SAP has been processed. The data changes constantly but there always has to be a line manager I'd. The number is there for relational, rather than the highest number wins. Our organisation structure has taken a wile but every employee has a line manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some test data I used to create my answer (I slightly renamed a few columns for ease of reading, added another record to demonstrate functionality):

```
CREATE TABLE #test (EmployeeID INT, SiteID INT, LineManagerID INT, OwnerID INT)
INSERT INTO #test
    (
        EmployeeID
        ,SiteID
        ,LineManagerID
        ,OwnerID
    )
VALUES
    (
        1234  -- EmployeeID
        ,123 -- SiteID
        ,2345 -- LineManagerID
        ,NULL -- OwnerID
    ),
    (
        2345  -- EmployeeID
        ,123 -- SiteID
        ,3456 -- LineManagerID
        ,NULL -- OwnerID
    ),
    (
        3456  -- EmployeeID
        ,123 -- SiteID
        ,5678 -- LineManagerID
        ,NULL -- OwnerID
    ),
    (
        5678  -- EmployeeID
        ,123 -- SiteID
        ,1002 -- LineManagerID
        ,NULL -- OwnerID
    ),
    (
        1002  -- EmployeeID
        ,567 -- SiteID
        ,1103 -- LineManagerID
        ,NULL -- OwnerID
    ),
    (
        1103  -- EmployeeID
        ,568 -- SiteID
        ,6669 -- LineManagerID
        ,NULL -- OwnerID
    )
```

Then your `UPDATE` will use a recursive CTE to figure out the top LineManagerID for each SiteID.

```
;WITH UserCTE
     AS (SELECT EmployeeID,
                SiteID,
                LineManagerID,
                0 AS [Level],
                NULL AS mgrEmpID
         FROM   #test

         UNION ALL

         SELECT usr.EmployeeID,
                usr.SiteID,
                usr.LineManagerID,
                mgr.[Level] + 1,
                mgr.EmployeeID AS mgrEmpID
         FROM   #test AS usr
         INNER JOIN UserCTE AS mgr ON usr.LineManagerID = mgr.EmployeeID AND usr.SiteID <> mgr.SiteID
         WHERE  usr.LineManagerID IS NOT NULL
         )
UPDATE t
SET t.OwnerID = u.mgrEmpID
FROM #test t
LEFT JOIN UserCTE u ON t.SiteID = u.SiteID AND u.[Level] = 1
```

And here's what the table looks like after the `UPDATE`:

```
EmployeeID  SiteID  LineManagerID   OwnerID
1234        123     2345            1002
2345        123     3456            1002
3456        123     5678            1002
5678        123     1002            1002
1002        567     1103            1103
1103        568     6669            NULL
```

Comment: Amazing, the query returns the results I require.  I will take a copy of out database and have a go.  Thank you for your wisdom :)